# Android: How to save the best score in a game?

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner programmer and I create a game for android and I came across a problem that I want after finishing the game to show me the best score that I managed to achieve in playing this game I made a condition

```
if(DOD> sharedPreferences.getInt("DOD_SHA",0));
```

of course I use sharedPreferences to save the best score here but this condition doesn't work at all and my sharedPreference takes any value even less than the last score

```
public class EndScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView Levelwys,war;
    Button GotoMenu;
    int DOD,ODE,MNO,PIE,DZI,POT,SIL,LOG;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_end_screen);

        Levelwys = findViewById(R.id.textView15);
        war = findViewById(R.id.textView19);
        GotoMenu = findViewById(R.id.button);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("com.example.goodmath", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int number = intent.getIntExtra(GameSingleActivity.LEVEL, 0);
        DOD = intent.getIntExtra("DOD", 0);
        ODE = intent.getIntExtra("ODE", 0);
        MNO = intent.getIntExtra("MNO", 0);
        PIE = intent.getIntExtra("PIE", 0);
        DZI = intent.getIntExtra("DZI", 0);
        POT = intent.getIntExtra("POT", 0);
        SIL = intent.getIntExtra("SIL", 0);
        LOG = intent.getIntExtra("LOG", 0);
        Levelwys.setText(String.valueOf(number));
        String test = String.valueOf(DOD);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), test, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Save();

        GotoMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                GotoMenu();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }

    void GotoMenu()
    {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }

    void Save()
    {
        if(DOD> sharedPreferences.getInt("DOD_SHA",0));
        {
            editor.putInt("DOD_SHA",DOD);
            editor.apply ();
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            war.setText(String.valueOf(sharedPreferences.getInt("DOD_SHA",DOD)));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Accepted answer notes it was a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typo in your if condition:

```
if(DOD> sharedPreferences.getInt("DOD_SHA",0));
```

You have added extra semicolon at the end of this line. Because of this, the code below this condition was always called. 
Delete this semicolon and everything should works fine:

```
if(DOD> sharedPreferences.getInt("DOD_SHA",0))
    {
        editor.putInt("DOD_SHA",DOD);
        editor.apply ();
        editor.commit();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        war.setText(String.valueOf(sharedPreferences.getInt("DOD_SHA",DOD)));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you .
One thing and does so much;)